# .NET Maui Access underlying data model in collectionview itemtemplate

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui, itemtemplate

Is there any way, to access the underlying object (item) when using contentview as itemtemplate, or when the contentview is used this way, it is just a tool to display bound properties from particular object ?

Thanks for answers

Hello everyone, I have this setup on contentpage:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="TheCollection" x:DataType="VMMonkeysViewModel"                                        ItemsSource="{Binding MonkeyList}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="MonkeyCollection_SelectionChanged">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MMonkeyDataModel">
                                <cview:MonkeyView/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

cview:MonkeyView is a contentview with bindings to MMonkeyDataModel, which has some buttons in it, the issue is, that in MonkeyView code-behind, I cant get access to underlying data model (MMonkeyDataModel) to use it in button commands (the contentview's bindingContext is always null in code behind).

Edit:

To be more precise. MonkeyView has this code inside a method:

```
_CurrentMonkey = this.BindingContext as MMonkeyDataModel;
        if (_CurrentMonkey != null)
        {
         // do some stuff with _CurrentMonkey
        }
```

This.BindingContext returns always null (even in constructor).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't understand what problem you're having. Can you please describe the issue or question more precisely? Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do and the specific problem you're having

Comment: I tried to update my description, simply put, collection view item is displayed using an itemtemplate (in this case MonkeyView) in monkeyview code-behind i want to access the item that is displayed

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why are you doing it in the view and not the VM?  You can try using the `OnBindingContextChanged` event

Comment: (1) I don't see any code that [sets collectionview's ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0). (2) ItemsSource won't be a single item, it will be a collection of items. "CurrentMonkey" sounds like you want collectionview's current [selected item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: The default BindingContext for MonkeyView is each MMonkeyDataModel in collection. You could use bindings in xaml.